# Error al usar let en C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de linq donde dejo este ejemplo:

```
string[] postres = { "pay de manzana", "pastel de chocolate", "manzana caramelizada", "fresas con crema", "pay de manzana y pera" };

IEnumerable<string> misPays = from item1 in postres
                                          let manzanitas =
                                            from item2 in postres
                                            where item2.Contains("manzana")
                                            orderby item2
                                            select item2
                                          where manzanitas.Contains("pay")
                                          select item1;

            foreach (string el in misPays)
                Console.WriteLine(el);
```

no funciona, y el que da el tutorial no explico porque. Le estube dando vueltas pero con mi pobre conocimiento aun no pude resolverlo

antes habia mostrado este que si funciona

```
IEnumerable<string> miPay = from el in
                                            (
                                                from el in postres
                                                where el.Contains("manzana")
                                                orderby el
                                                select el
                                            )
                                        where el.Contains("pay")
                                        select el;

            foreach (string el in miPay)
                Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no funciona xq el último contains lo que pregunta es si la colleción manzanita que son los postres que contengan manzana tienen la palabra "pay", es decir esa condición retornará verdadero siempre que sea exactamente la palabra "pay" nada más, el segundo ejemplo es una consulta anidada, consulta primero los que contengan "manzana" y después de esos consulta los que tengan "pay", el problema es que en el primer ejemplo el `Contains` se aplica a una colección y en el segundo a una cadena, para que funcione puede hacerlo así

```
 string[] postres = { "pay de manzana", "pastel de chocolate", "manzana caramelizada", "fresas con crema", "pay de manzana y pera" };

            IEnumerable<string> misPays = from item1 in postres
                                          let manzanitas =
                                            from item2 in postres
                                            where item2.Contains("manzana")
                                            orderby item2
                                            select item2
                                          where manzanitas.Contains(item1) && item1.Contains("pay")
                                          select item1;

            foreach (string el in misPays)
                Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Saludos